# A FromForm parameter becomes null when posting a lot of data

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have the following ASP.NET controller action:

```
[RequestSizeLimit(100_000_000_000)]
[RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = long.MaxValue, ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue)]
[HttpPost("api/files")]
[Authorize(Policy = Perm.FileCreate)]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAsync([FromForm] CreateFileDto files)
{
  ...
}
```

where `CreateFileDto` is:

```
public class CreateFileDto
{
    public required ICollection<IFormFile> Images { get; init; } = new List<IFormFile>();
}
```

This works, I can upload 1000 files without any problem. However, when I try uploading 2000 files, the `files` parameter is `null`.

Am I running into a configurable limit somewhere? How can I fix this?

Comment: I believe the limit is set to 1024 by default.  Try with: builder.Services.Configure<FormOptions>(x => x.ValueCountLimit = int.MaxValue); In program.cs.  (or set to a reasonable limit)  Strange that you didn't receive a bad request error, though.

Comment: See here for full list of options: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.features.formoptions?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Comment: Thanks, that helped! Actually, putting it in Program.cs didn't help, but this attribute on the action helped:

```
    [RequestFormLimits(
        MultipartBodyLengthLimit = long.MaxValue,
        ValueCountLimit = int.MaxValue,
        ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue
    )]
```

Consider writing up an answer if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in startup.cs file in ConfigureService method :-

```
 // Increase form limits
services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
{
  options.ValueCountLimit = int.MaxValue; //Maximum number of form entries

  options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = long.MaxValue; //Maximum length of multipart body

});
```